# What are the crown and energy costs for crafting each level of item?

Tags: spiral-knights

I've noticed that all 1-star and 2-star items seem to require the same amount of crown and energy inputs for each creation - 10E/200C and 50E/400C respectively.

Are these costs *always* the same for each star level?
And if so, what are the costs associated with each star level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spiral Knights Wiki](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Crafting) has the skinny on crafting:

> Alchemy Machines are located in Haven,
>   Moorcroft Manor, and Emberlight. Haven
>   has several Alchemy Machines which can
>   be found in Guildhalls, the Bazaar,
>   Arcade, and the Town Square. The cost
>   of crafting an item depends on its
>   star level, and generally doubles with
>   each additional star.
>
> - Alchemy Cost:
> - ★☆☆☆☆: 200 crowns/ 10 energy
> - ★★☆☆☆: 400 crowns/ 50 energy
> - ★★★☆☆: 1,000 crowns/ 200 energy
> - ★★★★☆: 2,500 crowns/ 400 energy
> - ★★★★★: 5,000 crowns/ 800 energy
>
> Usually, crafting
>   is much cheaper than buying the item
>   pre-made from a vendor, and also gives
>   the added possibility of creating a
>   unique variant (see below). Pre-made
>   items increase in price as their star
>   level increases. Thus, items with a
>   high star level are generally cheaper
>   to craft than to buy pre-made.

Comment: Ouch, they don't half ramp up those energy costs. Oh well, maybe I'll just stop for a bit once I've finished my 2-star set.

Comment: @DMA - you can knock off 100 CE from each alchemy thing if you craft with full mist energy. The good news is that once you have the items you want, you'll never need to craft again. (Until a new content patch, perhaps)

Comment: Ah, well for the moment @Raven, I'm a fairly new "free" player, so mist energy is all I have. Once I've a full set of 2-star stuff - only a shield to go - I guess I'll then stop buying things for a while and build up enough crowns to buy some of that real energy to craft higher stuff with. Will have to see.

Comment: Of course, the implication here is that, while 1 star and 2 star items can be crafted by anyone, you **must** have Crystal Energy to craft 3-5 star items.

Answer (score 1):

As of the [July 30th, 2013](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Release_Notes_2013-07-30) patch:

```
Alchemy Machines are located in Haven, Moorcroft Manor, and Emberlight. Haven has several Alchemy Machines which can be found in Guildhalls, the Bazaar, Arcade, and the Town Square. The cost of crafting an item depends on its star level, and generally doubles with each additional star.

Alchemy Cost:
★☆☆☆☆: 200 crowns
★★☆☆☆: 400 crowns
★★★☆☆: 1,000 crowns
★★★★☆: 2,500 crowns
★★★★★: 5,000 crowns

Usually, crafting is much cheaper than buying the item pre-made from a vendor, and also gives the added possibility of creating a unique variant (see below). Pre-made items increase in price as their star level increases. Thus, items with a high star level are generally cheaper to craft than to buy pre-made.
```